# WordPress Rest API get total post count

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the following to get posts

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

I the max limit on posts is 100 per request.

So I would have to make multiple requests to get all posts.

How can I get the total post count so I know how many requests I have to make?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

The response headers include this data:

> To determine how many pages of data are available, the API returns two
>   header fields with every paginated response:
>
> - `X-WP-Total`: the total number of records in the collection
> - `X-WP-TotalPages`: the total number of pages encompassing all available
>     records
>
> By inspecting these header fields you can determine how much more data is available within the API.

via https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

also for reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250589

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead for pagination. It returns all the posts on my site.

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[posts_per_page]=10`

filter[category_name]

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=country&filter[posts_per_page]=111`